# How to save polyline in Database? using google maps and JS?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, google-maps

Currently I am working on a project where I need to store polyline in database and afterwords display it on Map.
I am using getPath() method to get coordinates. But It is giving "undefined" output.
Code is written in JS and AJAX call is used to store the data.
Webpage is in codeigniter framework.

Function is  :

function submitInformationForm(){

```
            var path = [];
            path = poly.getPath();
            var pathLength = path.length;
            var _b = path.j;
            var str = [];
            str = '';
            if(pathLength!=0){
                for(var i=0; i<pathLength; i++){

                    var point = _b[i].H +','+ _b[i].L;
                    str = str + point;
                    if(i < (pathLength-1)){
                        str = str+'-';
                    }
                }
                if(info_name && info_description && color && str!=''){


                    $.ajax({
                        url: '<?php echo site_url('admin/show_map/fill_information');?>',
                        type: 'post',
                        data:{
                            'name' : info_name,
                            'color' : color,
                            'latlngs' : str,


                        },
                        success: function(resp){

                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    alert("All fields are mendatory...");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: How do you get the path/string back out to load into the map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this documentation.Hope this helps.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry?hl=en